# Change file extensions from uppercase to lowercase in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, batch-rename

I'm copying files from my Nikon camera to my iMac several times each week using Nikon Transfer 2 which changes the file name but keeps the uppercase extension.

I spend a lot of time changing 100'ds of files from .NEF to .nef or .JPG to .jpg. I can't do batch processing in Finder so I have to change all the file extensions one by one. Is there any easy way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Open *Terminal.app*, and use `cd` to navigate to the folder with the images. To do that, type `cd`, a space, and drag your folder onto Terminal. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Now, copy and paste this:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.NEF; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.NEF}.nef"; done
```

This will make all .NEF extensions lowercase, and it will do so recursively.

Comment: shopt -s globstar don't work on OSX by default. You can make it work by installing bash 4 with homebrew, as described here : http://mistermorris.com/blog/get-yourself-globstar-bash-4-for-your-mac-terminal/

Comment: You're right, I should add this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Renamer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/renamer-batch-rename-many/id402286241) [edit - oops, is not freeware] or [NameChanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/) [donationware]

[Source [3 Ways to batch rename files on Mac](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-easy-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-the-mac--mac-46999)]